# Best way for returning a pointer of a struct from a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I need some opinions on this matter. I need to know what is the best approach of tacking this problem.

If I need to return a pointer to a certain struct, can I return a pointer of type uint8_t that points to the start address of that struct or should it be a pointer to a struct?

For example assuming we have the following struct:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t type;
   uint8_t num;
   uint16_t Id;
} myStruct_t;

myStruct_t x[10];
```

And we have a function that should return a pointer to a certain element of x array based on the type. Now should the function be declared as follow:

```
int function_x( myStruct_t * ptr )
{
  ...
  //ptr = &x[0];
  memcpy( ptr, &x[0], sizeof(..) )
  return 0;
}
```

or can I declare it as:

```
int function_x( uint8_t * ptr )
{
  ...
  ptr = (uint8_t *)&x[0];
  return 0;
}
```

and in the later case we can just recast the by doing the following where we call the function:

```
....
myStruct_t resp;
int r;
r = function_x( (uint8_t *)&resp );
printf("%d\n", resp.type );
...
```

Both cases have been tested and proved to work BUT the question here is which approach is considered to be more acceptable approach and which is more frowned upon?

Comment: You seem to be asking for opinions, which would be off-topic for SO.  Nevertheless, I cannot resist at least commenting that you should prefer to avoid casting whenever possible.

Comment: My question would be, why do you need to return the uint8_t? I'm not aware of any drawbacks to it in terms of working, but as the saying goes, programming languages are made for programmers, not computers, or we would write everything in 1's and 0's. Why make the code harder to understand by using a type that is less understandable to the next person that has to read the code?

Comment: Note also, however, that *both* your alternatives are seriously flawed.  Assigning a value to `ptr` inside your function will not have any visible effect outside the function.  You probably want to pass an argument of type `myStruct_t **`, and set the value of its referrent, e.g. `*ptr = &x[0]`.  Alternatively, if you pass a `myStruct_t *` then you could set the value of its refferrent like so: `*ptr = x[0]`.  Either of these alternatives communicates information back to the caller, unlike your example code, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: Guys I understand that this code is not 100% correct but the argument here is about the best approach of doing the returning of a struct element value

Comment: First, set your terms straight. You return a value with a `return` statement. Your function does not return anything useful. It always returns an integer value 0. It **accepts** a pointer to a struct. Second, if you want to pass a pointer to a certain struct to a function, pass a pointer to that very struct to a function. Why consider any other option? How passing a pointer to some unrelated type could possibly be of any benefit?